# How to import Gradle Projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I used libGDX for an longer time and now after an reinstallation I want to use it with Gradle.

I downloaded the setup.jar and created an project with it like described [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle). I imported that into IntelliJ and setted for the core Package the dependency to graddle_wrapper and for the 2nd Package "desktop" to core.
I run build.gradle, without problems.

But still, IntelliJ is not able to recognise the libGDX Packages - they are red.

What do I have todo else in order to get libGDX running? (Or any other Project with Gradle)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do an `Import Project` or `Open...` and navigate to `build.gradle` file. This should be enough for IntelliJ to figure out the dependencies and set up the project.

Comment: I had a maven project open on IntelliJ. I deleted pom.xml and created build.gradle.  IntelliJ would not automatically "transform" my project into a gradle project. I could not find a menu otpion to do that. So, I closed IntelliJ and reopened the project. Only then it showed me the option at the bottom-right of the screen to import the project as a gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

check out this link [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#import-project)

**Summary :**

1. open Intellij Idea Welcome Page
2. press Ctrl + Shift + A
   a search Field will show up
3. type from existing sources
   select the item import project from existing sources
4. a message saying 'load groovy project' will show up in Intellij Idea, click on it to load the project as a groovy project