# How to run a SpringBoot application from Java IDE for Professional Developers (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, ide

I am new using IntelliJ IDEA , I just download this example and imported to IntelliJ IDEA

https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/

but I don't know how to run it. I just click run but I don't see the console like Eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Gradle Projects in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256356/how-to-import-gradle-projects-in-intellij)

Comment: I think I've just made a big instruction in this post, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696454/import-source-code-meant-for-eclipse-spring-sts-into-intellij/56704461#56704461.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to the main class and click on the green triangle on the left of the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Shift+ Alt + F10` and you will find the option to run.