# import source code (meant for eclipse spring STS) into intellij

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, import, spring-tool-suite

How to import and run spring mvc github source code meant for Eclipse Spring STS into IntelliJ?

What I did:

1. downloaded working spring mvc project source code zip file https://github.com/simplyi/springmvc-ws?fbclid=IwAR2xKg6Oh0YHLuVJ2YEh2vt6cr1u3-4E4IzKnPMDJVc6nvI-BN6pRaPMKHQ
2. 'import' upon starting Intellij
3. don't know what configurations to pick so got a lot of errors. SO, followed this https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/java/IntellijMaven.html?fbclid=IwAR3JaAw6dF2jX9k4fxxKg37j8mpNI2dNTEqupVULzLrk83G_wEtN4beNJsI
4. BUT got error: 
   ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'lagom' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories

So, I'm giving up on this tutorial in above link.

Here is gyazo screenshot of Intellij terminal errors:
https://gyazo.com/7f83cca2baeff6ca383885f814325477

This gyazo screenshot shows external libraries:
https://gyazo.com/6e2898508b64061ebf726fc46881b0ef

***How to import this source code into Intellij & run/test the webapp?***

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to run lagom specific maven goals from lagom plugin, but your application is NOT a lagom app. This will fail - you have no lagom plugins defined in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

The project you linked to looks like a standard *maven* Spring Boot application.

1. Download and unzip the project
2. Start IntelliJ
3. At the Welcome screen, select "Open" (instead of import)
4. Navigate to the project folder/directory and click "Open"

That's it!  IntelliJ will detect the maven structure and will setup the project appropriately (downloading dependencies, etc., which might take a couple of minutes).

To start the application, you can click on the "maven" panel on the right side of the screen, find the `spring-boot` plugin, and select `spring-boot:run`.

ps. it looks like this particular project was written for JDK 8.  If you're using JDK 9 or above then you may need to make changes to make the project run.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and run the Spring Boot application from your link.
It starts and passes the tests.

## Short answer

Looks that your problem is what class you're running.

- Run `\springmvc-ws\src\test\java\com\appsdeveloperblog\app` package as JUnit to run the tests.
- Run `com.appsdeveloperblog.app.ws.MobileAppWsApplication` class as Spring Boot application to run the application.

## Long answer

What I've done to run the application and the tests:

- Clone the project from github: run `git clone https://github.com/simplyi/springmvc-ws.git` in the console.
  The project will be cloned into `springmvc-ws` sub-directory of from where you executed `git clone`.
- In IDEA, select `File` -> `Open` (from keyboard: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>), select the cloned `springmvc-ws` folder.
- Select OK. If required, answer to open it in current or new window.
- Wait for the project to be imported (no running operations displayed in the bottom status bar).

### To run the application

- Open class `MobileAppWsApplication` (you can type it in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> as a quick "Go to class" shortcut).
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.
- Select execution with Spring Boot icon and select `Run`. See the screenshot below.
  [image: Running the application]
- In `Run` tool window at the bottom, you'll see that the application has started on `localhost:8080` under the context-path `/mobile-app-ws`:

```
2019-06-21 15:42:51.585  INFO 31920 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/mobile-app-ws'
2019-06-21 15:42:51.588  INFO 31920 --- [           main] c.a.app.ws.MobileAppWsApplication        : Started MobileAppWsApplication in 8.688 seconds (JVM running for 10.143)
```

- In the `Endpoints` tab of this `Run` tool window, you can see the web-service endpoints of the started application.

### To run the tests

- Stop the application if it is running (Red `Stop` button in `Run` tool window), to not have the clashing ports.
- In `Project` window (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>), select the directory `\springmvc-ws\src\test\java\com\appsdeveloperblog` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> on it.
- Select the point with JUnit (arrows) icon on it and then select `Run` point. See the screenshot below.
  [image: Run tests configuration from project tree]
- `Run` tool window will activate. Wait for the tests to pass. You can expand the directory to see the tests results.